# Массив, вывод в тег li по очереди

Tags: javascript

```
const S_FUNC = ['Описание 1', 'Описание 2', 'Описание 3', 'Описание 4'];
```

Не понимаю как по очереди засунуть в li каждое описание, вот к примеру чтобы получилось так:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">Описание блока 1</li>
    <li class="item">Описание блока 2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">Описание блока 3</li>
    <li class="item">Описание блока 4</li>
</ul>
```

Либо тут не массив нужен, а объект, чтобы было удобнее писать для каждого своё описание, не знаю...

Пытался что-то такое сотворить:

```
let sFuncText = document.body.querySelectorAll('.item');

for(let i = 0; i < S_FUNC.length; i++ ){
    sFuncText.innerHTML = S_FUNC[i];
}
```

Не силён в JS. Направьте в правильную сторону. Код готовый писать не обязательно :)

Comment: Попробуйте так `sFuncText[i].innerHTML = S_FUNC[i];`. Хотя, лучше конечно сделать объект, вместо массива.

Comment: Да, оно вывелось туда, но теперь в item весь массив, а нужно, чтобы в первом li был первое описание и тд... спасибо)

Comment: Вы не правильно скопировали код, видимо. Посмотрите внимательно и найдите у себя расхождение с моим кодом.

Comment: Спасибо всем, все варианты отличные, я уже написал с ваших вариантов свой подходящий код!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы хотите. Доработанный ваш пример.

```js
const S_FUNC = ['Описание 1', 'Описание 2', 'Описание 3', 'Описание 4'];

let sFuncText = document.body.querySelectorAll('.item');

for (let i = 0; i < S_FUNC.length; i++) {
  sFuncText[i].innerHTML = S_FUNC[i];
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Описание блока 1</li>
  <li class="item">Описание блока 2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Описание блока 3</li>
  <li class="item">Описание блока 4</li>
</ul>
```

Но лучше сделать вот так.

```js
const S_FUNC = {
  ul1: ['Описание 1', 'Описание 2'],
  ul2: ['Описание 3', 'Описание 4']
};

let sFuncText = document.body.querySelectorAll('.item');

const uls = document.querySelectorAll('.list').forEach(ul => {
  ul.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach((li, i) => {
    li.innerText = S_FUNC[ul.id][i];
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="list" id="ul1">
  <li class="item">Описание блока 1</li>
  <li class="item">Описание блока 2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list" id="ul1">
  <li class="item">Описание блока 3</li>
  <li class="item">Описание блока 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Создаст список на с количеством элементов из массива `S_FUNC`

```js
const S_FUNC = ['Описание 1', 'Описание 2', 'Описание 3', 'Описание 4'];
const list = document.getElementById('list');
S_FUNC.forEach(item=>{
  let li = document.createElement('li')
  li.innerText = item
  list.append(li)
})
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```